# how to publish post on facebook page wall as admin using facebook php sdk v4 and graph api 2.x

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

how to publish post on Facebook page wall as page admin user using facebook php sdk v4 and graph api 2.x?

I have spent lot of hours but mostly articles are old(examples with old Facebook PHP SDK) and bit confusing

I have figured out following steps

*Step 1 : Redirect application to Facebook for logging admin 

Step 2 : Obtain user access token (short lived) 

Step 3 : Obtain user access token(long lived) by exchanging short lived token

Step 4 : Obtain Page access token*

Can you explain please which functions of Facebook PHP SDK I need to call for above steps
or you can give me url of some code example?

OR

If I am wrong then please correct me
Thanks for advance

=======================
Note:

- I have created application for app_id and app_secret
- I have created Facebook page
- I am using Facebook PHP SDK 4
- Facebook PHP SDK 4 uses graph API 2.x (I assume)

Answer (score 2):

I have a [tutorial that explains how to achieve posting to a page](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/23/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page-using-graph-api-v2-x-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/) using the PHP SDK v4.0.x and Graph API v.x.

Essentially, you can get a Page Access Token by doing the following:

```
// get page access token
$access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $page_id,  array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))
    ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// save access token in variable for later use  
$access_token = $access_token['access_token'];
```

Then you can make a second API call to post something to a given page using the access token we obtained above:

```
// post to page
$page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'name' => 'Facebook API: Posting As A Page using Graph API v2.x and PHP SDK 4.0.x',
    'link' => 'https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/23/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page-using-graph-api-v2-x-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/',
    'caption' => 'The Facebook API lets you post to Pages you administrate via the API. This tutorial shows you how to achieve this using the Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.x and Graph API 2.x.',
    'message' => 'Check out my new blog post!',
  ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// return post_id
print_r( $page_post );
```

Comment: Facebook php api has no class like 'FacebookSession' at all –

Comment: This answer was posted 17 months ago @XCode. Do you honestly expect it to still work? The PHP SDK has changed significantly since then, as has the Facebook API itself.

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to get a never expire token:

```
    //get your access token for the app that you will use in 
    //https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

    //exchange it for long-term access token

    $accessToken='xxxxxxxxGet it above';
    $session = new FacebookSession($accessToken);
    $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/oauth/access_token', array(
        'grant_type' => 'fb_exchange_token',
        'client_id' => 'the client id for the app',
        'client_secret' => 'the client secret for the app',
        'fb_exchange_token' => $accessToken)))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();


    $LongTermUserAccessToken=$response['access_token'];


    $session = new FacebookSession($LongTermUserAccessToken);

    //get My User ID if you don't know 

    $response = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' ,  array( 'fields' => 'id' ) ))
        ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
    $meId=$response['id'];

    //get Tokes for all my pages the page that you are usig will have a never expire token
    //you can prove on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

    $response = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$meId.'/accounts' ))
        ->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    var_dump($response);die;
```

Comment: why do you say long-term access token if it change when user is logged out?

Comment: This is for publish on your own fan page (where you are the administrator), with this method you can get a no expire access token. You can logout but your token does't expire. This don't work for user, just for fan page admins

Comment: Facebook php api has no class like 'FacebookSession' at all

Comment: This answer use fb sdk 4.0.1